# How to write an R Data Frame to a Snowflake database table

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone know how to WRITE an R Data Frame to a new Snowflake database table?  I have a successful Snowflake ODBC connection created in R, and can successfully query from Snowflake.  The connection command is:  conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "Snowflake").

Now, I want to WRITE a data frame created in R back to Snowflake as a table.  I used the following command: dbWriteTable(conn, "*database.schema.tablename*", *R data frame name*).  Using this command successfully connects with Snowflake, but I get the following error message:  "Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 22000: Cannot perform CREATE TABLE. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name."

I am using a qualified database name in my "*database.schema.tablename*" argument in the dbWriteTable function.  I don't see how to employ "USE DATABASE" in my R function.  Any ideas??  Thank you!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API for [`DBI::dbWriteTable(…)`](https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/dbWriteTable.html) requires passing either the literal table name as a string, or as a properly quoted identifier:

> *`dbWriteTable(conn, name, value, ...)`*
>
> `conn`: A DBIConnection object, as returned by dbConnect().
>
> `name`: A character string specifying the **unquoted DBMS table name**, or the result of a call to dbQuoteIdentifier().
>
> `value`: a data.frame (or coercible to data.frame).

```r
dbWriteTable(conn, "database.schema.tablename", R data frame name)
```

Your code above will attempt to create a table *literally named* `"database.schema.tablename"`, using the database and schema context associated with the connection object.

For example, if your connection had a database `DB` and schema `SCH` set, this would have *succeeded* in creating a table called `DB.SCH."database.schema.tablename"`.

To define the database, schema and table names properly, use the [`DBI::Id`](https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/Id.html) class object with the right hierarchal order:

```r
table_id <- Id(database="database", schema="schema", table="tablename")
dbWriteTable(conn, table_id, R data frame name)
```

Behind the scenes, the `DBI::dbWriteTable(…)` function recognizes the `DBI::Id` class argument type for `name`, and [converts it into a quoted identifier](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/blob/eee573b3fc448d42ed942ddf137dd7b7f304fd0b/R/DBConnection.R#L621-L626) format via [`DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(…)`](https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/dbQuoteIdentifier.html) (as a convenience).

Comment: Thanks VERY much, Harsh, for your helpful response.  I really appreciate it.  I used the solution you suggested:  table_id <- Id(database="database", schema="schema", table="tablename"), and then followed with 
dbWriteTable(conn, table_id, R data frame name),  and it worked perfectly!!  Wow, this is great!  Thanks again!!

Comment: It worked for me, @Harsh J  the only thing is that the final table in Snowflake ends up with all column names being UPPER CASE. How can I keep the lower case name I had in my R data frame?

Comment: One clarification: the first field in `Id()` should be named `catalog` rather than `database`, as in `catalog = "database"`. More details [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/423#issuecomment-1867018411).

Answer (score 1):

For people coming to this now (2023), the method in the other answer no longer works. The current solution is to simply wrap your table's name in SQL from the DBI package. If df is your local dataframe and you want to create a table named database.schema.tablename, it would look like this:

```
dbWriteTable(conn, SQL("database.schema.tablename"), df)
```

Comment: If you encounter an issue with the first answer, it's likely because the argument `database` to `Id()` should actually be named `catalog`, as in `catalog = "database"`, rather than the code "no longer working." More details [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/423#issuecomment-1867018411).